# Protractor is not running features file from cucumber

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests, cucumber

I'm working in the implementation of cucumber with protractor and everything seems ok because is not failing but when I execute the termal said the 0 scenarios executed.

This is my conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  },

  specs: './features/login.feature',

  onPrepare: function(){
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize()
    browser.get('http:www.google.com')
  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
  },

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'features/steps/my_steps.js',
  }
};
```

this is the tree of my framework:

[image]

but when I execute `protractor conf.js`I have this output in terminal:

```
[17:27:45] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[17:27:45] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at    http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m00.000s
```

So I just want to know if I had something wrong on the conf.js or there is another command that I should execute to run the features file with protractor.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you configured the running of the `conf.js` file. For example.

`root
|
|_features
|_config
| |_conf.js
|_package.json`

If you are having a script in the package json that triggers protractor from the root of your project that is triggered with for example `npm test` from the root of you project, Protractor will then search files from `root/{config.specs}`

If you are running a script from for example the `./config`-folder then it will search from the `root/config/{config.specs}`.

So it depends from where you trigger you script in searching the feature-files

Comment: So you mean that my specs path is wrong? because i tried with differents path in fact if I add a path to the test just using protractor is working is execute the tests but when I add the path pointing to the features of cucumber is not executed nothing.

Comment: @burq24, see [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L192).
Can you also give an example of the featurefile?

Comment: Sure this is what I have on the feature `Feature: Running Cucumber with Protractor
  Scenario: Protractor and Cucumber Test
      Given Say Hi`

Comment: And my steps file:
`module.exports = function(){
  this.Given(/Say Hi/, function () {
    console.log('Hi');
  });
}`